# C++ program with string class fails before main() breakpoint is hit, remove the string variable and it works as expected

Tags: c++, g++, cygwin, stdstring

My environment is

- Windows 10
- Cygwin64
- g++ 5.2.0

The following program works as expected (main executes without error, returns 0)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
//#define USE_STRING 1

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout << "begin " << endl;
#ifdef USE_STRING
    string w("fish");
#endif
    cout << "blah " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but if I uncomment the #define USE_STRING the program crashes before it can even hit a breakpoint in main.

Here is how I compiled:

```
g++ -ggdb -v    my_string.cc   -o my_string
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-pc-cygwin
Configured with: /cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.2.0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-5.2.0/configure --srcdir=/cygdrive/i/szsz/tmpp/gcc/gcc-5.2.       0-1.x86_64/src/gcc-5.2.0 --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --localstatedir=/var --sysconfdir=/etc --docdir=/usr/share/doc/gcc --ht       mldir=/usr/share/doc/gcc/html -C --build=x86_64-pc-cygwin --host=x86_64-pc-cygwin --target=x86_64-pc-cygwin --without-libiconv-pr       efix --without-libintl-prefix --libexecdir=/usr/lib --enable-shared --enable-shared-libgcc --enable-static --enable-version-speci       fic-runtime-libs --enable-bootstrap --enable-__cxa_atexit --with-dwarf2 --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=ada,c,c++,fortran,       lto,objc,obj-c++ --enable-graphite --enable-threads=posix --enable-libatomic --enable-libgomp --disable-libitm --enable-libquadma       th --enable-libquadmath-support --enable-libssp --enable-libada --enable-libgcj-sublibs --disable-java-awt --disable-symvers --wi       th-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/ecj.jar --with-gnu-ld --with-gnu-as --with-cloog-include=/usr/include/cloog-isl --without-libiconv-pre       fix --without-libintl-prefix --with-system-zlib --enable-linker-build-id
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-ggdb' '-v' '-o' 'my_string.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/ -Dunix -idirafter        /usr/lib/../lib/../include/w32api -idirafter ../../include/w32api my_string.cc -quiet -dumpbase my_string.cc -mtune=generic -marc       h=x86-64 -auxbase my_string -ggdb -version -o /tmp/cc6aWK4I.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 5.2.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.2.0, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3
warning: GMP header version 6.0.0 differs from library version 6.1.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++"
ignoring duplicate directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin"
ignoring duplicate directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/usr/local/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include-fixed"
ignoring nonexistent directory "/bin/../lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/include"
ignoring nonexistent directory "../../include/w32api"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++/x86_64-pc-cygwin
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include/c++/backward
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/include-fixed
 /usr/include
 /usr/lib/../lib/../include/w32api
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 5.2.0 (x86_64-pc-cygwin)
        compiled by GNU C version 5.2.0, GMP version 6.0.0, MPFR version 3.1.3, MPC version 1.0.3
warning: GMP header version 6.0.0 differs from library version 6.1.0.
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: 594d57f36425b84b161aac261544e04e
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-ggdb' '-v' '-o' 'my_string.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 as -v -o /tmp/ccEdjvZ0.o /tmp/cc6aWK4I.s
GNU assembler version 2.25.2 (x86_64-pc-cygwin) using BFD version (GNU Binutils) 2.25.2
COMPILER_PATH=/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/:/bin/../lib/gcc/
LIBRARY_PATH=/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/:/bin/../lib/gcc/:/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../lib/:/li       b/../lib/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-ggdb' '-v' '-o' 'my_string.exe' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
 /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/collect2.exe -plugin /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/cyglto_plugin.dll -plugin-opt       =/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe -plugin-opt=-fresolution=/tmp/cc6lfDyO.res -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgc       c_s -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lcygwin -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-ladvapi32 -plugin-opt=-pass-thr       ough=-lshell32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-luser32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lkernel32 -plugin-opt=-pass-through=-lgcc_s -plugin-       opt=-pass-through=-lgcc --build-id -m i386pep --wrap _Znwm --wrap _Znam --wrap _ZdlPv --wrap _ZdaPv --wrap _ZnwmRKSt9nothrow_t --       wrap _ZnamRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdlPvRKSt9nothrow_t --wrap _ZdaPvRKSt9nothrow_t -Bdynamic --dll-search-prefix=cyg --tsaware -o m       y_string.exe -L/usr/lib/w32api /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../lib/crt0.o /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2       .0/crtbegin.o -L/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0 -L/bin/../lib/gcc -L/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../lib        -L/lib/../lib -L/usr/lib/../lib -L/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../.. /tmp/ccEdjvZ0.o -lstdc++ -lgcc_s -lgcc -lcygwi       n -ladvapi32 -lshell32 -luser32 -lkernel32 -lgcc_s -lgcc /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/../../../../lib/default-manifest.       o /bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/5.2.0/crtend.o
```

and the failure case in gdb looks like this:

```
$ gdb ./my_string
GNU gdb (GDB) Cygwin 7.9.1-1
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ./my_string...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x1004010fa: file my_string.cc, line 10.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/Admin/progs/c++/word_bubbles/my_string
[New Thread 107280.0x1a15c]
[New Thread 107280.0x1a2ac]
[New Thread 107280.0x1a050]
[New Thread 107280.0x1a3f4]
[Thread 107280.0x1a3f4 exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 107280.0x1a2ac exited with code 3221225785]
[Thread 107280.0x1a050 exited with code 3221225785]
During startup program exited with code 0xc0000139.
(gdb)
```

and lastly dynamic linkage looks like this:

```
$ ldd my_string
    ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7ffef9820000)
    KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNEL32.DLL  (0x7ffef9370000)
    KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7ffef6d10000)
```

I know the compiler output is a bit verbose but I'm trying to provide everything that might be needed to diagnose the problem.

EDIT 1: per suggestion, here is strace output:

```
$ strace ./my_string.exe
--- Process 105768 created
--- Process 105768 loaded C:\Windows\System32\ntdll.dll at 00007FFEF9820000
--- Process 105768 loaded C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll at 00007FFEF9370000
--- Process 105768 loaded C:\Windows\System32\KernelBase.dll at 00007FFEF6D10000
--- Process 105768 thread 107956 created
--- Process 105768 thread 56196 created
--- Process 105768 thread 92192 created
--- Process 105768 loaded E:\cygwin64\bin\cyggcc_s-seh-1.dll at 00000003F4260000
--- Process 105768 loaded E:\cygwin64\bin\cygstdc++-6.dll at 00000003EDF70000
--- Process 105768 loaded E:\cygwin64\bin\cygwin1.dll at 0000000180040000
--- Process 105768, exception c0000139 at 00007FFEF98B2F50
--- Process 105768 thread 92192 exited with status 0xc0000139
--- Process 105768 thread 105388 exited with status 0xc0000139
--- Process 105768 thread 56196 exited with status 0xc0000139
--- Process 105768 exited with status 0xc0000139
```

The process exception seems to be in one of the Windows DLL address ranges (ntdll.dll)?

EDIT 2: with strace, the following [error message window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMaYt.jpg) pops up

```
my_string.exe entry point not found

The entry point

_ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringlcSt11char_traitslcESalcEEC1EPKcRKS3_ could
not be located in the dynamic link library.
```

I have the Anaconda Python distribution installed and, in the successful program strace, I saw some lines with Anaconda paths so I temporarily renamed the Anaconda directory to ensure that recompiling & rerunning wouldn't find Anaconda but that had no effect.

Comment: it's your compiler, program is working fine, check : http://cpp.sh/6cej2

Comment: Your program ends with error code 0xc0000139, which means STATUS_ENTRYPOINT_NOT_FOUND. Apparently a DLL can't be found or doesn't match. Try to run your program under dependency walker or so (process monitor can also help), to see what DLL it tries to load at run time (the fact that it's dynamically loaded is probably the reason you don't see the error using ldd).

Comment: Eran, I ran strace and added the output info to the original description.

Presumably the missing entrypoint should resolve to the cygstdc++-6.dll DLL.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Try reinstalling gcc.

Comment: Thanks n.m.  I might try reinstalling again but I did that yesterday to resolve a different problem and I was careful on the reinstall to check that the gcc package versions matched up

Comment: final resolution: (1)  install virtualbox (2)  install Ubuntu linux on virtual box (3)  use g++ on Ubuntu.

much less headache this way.  Why didn't I find virtualbox sooner?